# Need help on html tables

Tags: html, html-table

Here's the code:Well my problem's the grade column I want it to be two columns but I don't know how can anyone help me.

```
<html>
<body>
<center>
<table border=2 width=50% cellspacing=5 cellpadding=8 bgcolor=yellow cols=2>
<tr>
<td rowspan=2>Name</td>
<td>ASP</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>Exer</td>
<td>Quiz</td>
<td>Recitation</td>
<td>Pe</td>
<td>Me</td>
<td>Grade</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Student 1<td rowspan=5>&nbsp;</td><td colspan=4 rowspan=5>&nbsp;</td><td rowspan=5>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Student 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Student 3</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>Student 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Student 5</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For your table widths, colors, padding, etc, you should consider using CSS - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets

Comment: Need to kill ... urge .. to .. indent code.

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want the "Grade" header to span two columns beneath it?  Add `colspan="2"` to the `<td>` element for that header and add new `<td>` elements to the row(s) beneath it.

```
<html>
<body>
<center>
<table border=2 width=50% cellspacing=5 cellpadding=8 bgcolor=yellow cols=2>
<tr>
<td rowspan=2>Name</td>
<td>ASP</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>Exer</td>
<td>Quiz</td>
<td>Recitation</td>
<td>Pe</td>
<td>Me</td>
<td colspan="2">Grade</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Student 1<td rowspan=5>&nbsp;</td><td colspan=4 rowspan=5>&nbsp;</td><td rowspan=5>&nbsp;</td><td rowspan=5>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Student 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Student 3</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>Student 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Student 5</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean.  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

The td element has a [colspan](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CBoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Ftags%2Fatt_td_colspan.asp&ei=NkwrTKH5NIW0lQeLo7GKBA&usg=AFQjCNHXD7BlJ4_LFyooF8o1ubUftwwyNw&sig2=QMSdSb5vYNaH8pLvQ3TFow) attribute that you can use to specify how many columns you want the td to occupy.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the "colspan and rowspan" section.

http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/tables.php